# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 15.10 not deteced and not detecting other devices

Tags: 15.10, bluetooth

I recently went back to Ubuntu after I had enough of my sloppy Windows 8.1. All is fine now, but I am unable to get my bluetooth to deteced other devices, and other devices are not detecting it. The bluetooth worked perfectly fine in Windows.
I should also add that I see the bluetooth icon on the tray and it is set to be both 'on' and 'visible', yet nothing happens.

I'm on a Acer Aspire V 15 black Edition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Output of

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e08e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. touchpad
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e092 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0773 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Output of usb-devices | awk '/e092/' RS=

```
~$ usb-devices | awk '/e092/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=09 Cnt=02 Dev#=  6 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0489 ProdID=e092 Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

Apologies for late reply, manauged to complicate things for myself, so I had to reinstall ubuntu 15.10. The problem still persists.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit to add `usb-devices | awk '/e092/' RS=`  You should file a bug report as I don't see this ID upstream

Comment: Please run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow the directions. Then you can post a link to the bug report here for reference.

Comment: Most likely it as QCA_ROME device.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Pilot6 in the comment above, this device uses the QCA_ROME driver. However, this precise bluetooth device is not currently supported in the kernel sources.

I'm on a Acer Aspire VN7-791 (quite similar model), with the same bluetooth device. Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0489:e092 Foxconn / Hon Hai
```

On my laptop, this device is actually used as a combo with Atheros Qualcomm Killer N1525 Wireless-AC [168c:003e], which has taken time to be integrated in the kernel (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184)

I could fix the problem using the same approach as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247195/bluetooth-scan-does-not-find-any-bluetooth-device.

Just follow the instructions from the link above, but add the following line in btusb.c instead (close to other QCA_ROME chipsets) :

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xe092), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
```

I submitted a bug report and patch here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1589023

Comment: This bugfix has been integrated in kernel 4.8 and Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak.